# is it necessary to use MakeGenericType method?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw code like this:

```
internal sealed class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> { }

public static class Program {
   public static void Main() {
      // Get a reference to the generic type's type object
      Type openType = typeof(MyDictionary<,>);
      
      // Close the generic type by using TKey=String, TValue=Int32
      Type closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeof(string), typeof(int));
      
      // Construct an instance of the closed type
      Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);

      Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
   }
}
```

But why we need to use the MakeGenericType method, why not just do:

```
...
Type concreteType= typeof(MyDictionary<string, int>);

Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);

Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```

the results are the same.

It looks like `MakeGenericType` method add extra unnecessity, so does `MakeGenericType` provide useful features that I overlook?

Comment: I'd say this code is just an example. When you know `string` and `int` and compile time, the whole code is useless and could just be `Object o = new Dictionary<string, int>();`. `MakeGenericType` becomes useful when you _don't_ know the type at compile time.

Comment: @RenéVogt - You have answered the OP very neatly and succinctly. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`MakeGenericType` is for when you don't know the type at compile time.  Therefore you are correct - you wouldn't really use the code you saw, as the types *were* known at compile time, so you may as well write `new MyDictionary<string, int>()`.

However, the code could rewritten like this:

```cs
internal sealed class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> { }

public static class Factory {
   public static MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>() {
      // Get a reference to the generic type's type object
      Type openType = typeof(MyDictionary<,>);
      
      // Close the generic type by using type constraints
      Type closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TKey), typeof(TValue));
      
      // Construct an instance of the closed type
      Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);

      return (MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>)o;
   }
}
```

These two would effectively create the same object:

```cs
var dictionary0 = new MyDictionary<string, int>();
var dictionary1 = Factory.Create<string, int>();

Console.WriteLine(dictionary0.GetType() == dictionary1.GetType());
// true
```

Even here it's not that useful because the return type requires generic constraints.  Where I use it is for situations that require an interface or abstract return type, but you need to create a generic implementation, for example:

```cs
internal sealed class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ISomeFeature { }

public static class Factory {
   public static ISomeFeature Create(Type key, Type value) {
      // Get a reference to the generic type's type object
      Type openType = typeof(MyDictionary<,>);
      
      // Close the generic type by using arguments
      Type closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(key, value);
      
      // Construct an instance of the closed type
      Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);

      return (ISomeFeature)o;
   }
}
```

Now suddenly it becomes a whole lot more useful.  Because it relies on `Type` objects instead of generic constraints, you can pass it types dynamically - i.e. at run time.

Comment: Your first sentence is excellent. The rest just confuses the matter. The OP had some specific code - I'd suggest any examples you provide should be based on the OP's code.

Comment: I answered it like that as the question wasn't about their code particularly, but some code they 'saw', so I was using a (working) example of my own code to explain what `MakeGenericType()` does - which is what the question was.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO!** it is not *necessary* to use `makeGenericType`, but sometimes it's a necessity

---

Generics are best used when you know the types at *compile time*. In fact there is a good argument that if you *don't* know the types at compile time, you probably shouldnt be using generics!

That said, there are often times when you need to use a generic implementation (perhaps a 3rd party library) and you only know the types at runtime... that is where Reflection, and specifically `MakeGenericType` comes in.

You code was no doubt an example of how to do this, because actually that code is only doing

```
var dict = new MyDictionary<string,int>();
Console.WriteLine(dict.GetType());
```

Assuming the types were known at compile time.

Comment: "if you don't know the types at compile time, you probably shouldnt be using generics" - I don't think that this is a true statement. It's just more difficult to use generics if you don't know the types at run-time. But that's the crux of the OP's question and I think you should be tackling to answer that.